# Facebook Open Graph Music Confusion

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i just spent EXACTLY 8 hours of my life.
4 hours i tried to figure out what the problem is and debug.

### The Problem

i'm trying to add meta tags to my webpage wich has a song on it. i want people who share the link to play the track on facebook as well.

so i found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/) i read it very good documentation.

then i tried implementing it, here is my code.

```
<html class="local_en_US" xmlns:music="http://ogp.me/ns/music#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">

<meta property="og:type" content="music.song" />
<meta property="music:musician" content="http://testappwebsite.dyndns-office.com/artist/sarya-al-sawas/" />
<meta property="music:duration" content="619" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://testappwebsite.dyndns-office.com/m/pics/artists/l.4eeea466d2fe79.75675583.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://testappwebsite.dyndns-office.com/track/sarya-al-sawas-mnalbortom-al-ta7tani/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="BeatBase" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="135615343218651" />
<meta property="og:audio" content="http://testappwebsite.dyndns-office.com/m/tracks/t.4eef1d812c56f8.45560770.mp3" />
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/vnd.facebook.bridge" />
```

Then i tried sharing the url on my status to test, and i didnt get any play button.
i went to debug.

[This is the result](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://testappwebsite.dyndns-office.com/track/sarya-al-sawas-mnalbortom-al-ta7tani/).

by the way the last 4 hours went for searching the web for clues.

i found some.

[Facebook Music Bridge (confused me even more.)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/bridge/)

[ogp.com didnt found any answers](http://ogp.com)

Answer (score 5):

It's in the first line of the documentation you were reading at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

> Facebook Open Graph Music is only available to whitelisted partners at
>   this time.

So basically Spotify, Rdio, MOG, et al. are allowed to use these parameters because Facebook specifically allowed them to do so.

Comment: How to become a whitelisted partner ? Where is the form ?